# Java Android low resolution fonts

Tags: java, android, fonts

I am playing around with Java for Android and I've noticed that fonts is in really low quality. Is there anyway to improve that?

(Tried to attach a image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW3G5.png here's the link if it didn't work)

The text on the left is an image and the text to the right is drawn from the canvas. They both use the same font: Leelawadee Bold (http://fontzone.net/font-details/Leelawadee+Bold/)

I am drawing the fonts with the "*canvas.drawText()*" method.

Comment: Did you turn on anti-aliasing via `setAntiAlias(true)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Paint.setAntiAlias(true)` and `Paint.setSubPixelText(true)` on the paint object you are using when drawing your text.

Comment: Thank you, but how much does that affect the cpu?

Comment: It will add a few CPU cycles, but nothing that should really affect your performance. Measure it with/without and see!